# From unemployed to self-employed/freelancer, how is my 401K & IRA setup?

Tags: united-states, 401k, roth-ira, rollover

Recently lost my job and decided to try out the freelancer route. I am in my early 40s and I expect to make about $150k before tax. I have a few questions about setting up a my 401k and IRA.

Already existing accounts:

- 401k plan with old employer, about $22k (Fidelity)
- Traditional IRA, about $14k (Vanguard)
- Rollover IRA, $0 (Fidelity)

What I am planning to do:

1. Rollover the Traditional IRA (Vanguard) into a Rollover IRA (Fidelity)
2. Rollover the old 401K (Fidelity) into a Rollover IRA (Fidelity)
3. Create a backdoor Roth IRA
4. Transfer the funds ($36K) from the Rollover IRA into the backdoor Roth IRA
5. Set up a solo 401k (Fidelity)
6. For 2020, contribute $57K into the solo 401K and $6000 into the backdoor Roth IRA

I know I am late to the retirement game. That's why I'd like to max out the contributions. Please let me know if I am missing something or something is wrong. Very much appreciate the help!